# Spark App using Scala and SBT in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, sbt

Can any please tell me, how to create a new Spark project using Scala and SBT in Eclipse? I googled a lot and find most of the Tutorials says to Create a project structure out side eclipse, package it using "sbt package", then import it in Eclipse using "sbt eclipse". Is their any way to create project directly in Eclipse and also to package it using SBT in eclipse itself? Thanks
Ref - http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I start a new Scala project is:

- Creating a base project using Giter8. There are a lot of templates for different types of Scala problems say Spark, Akka or Play projects
- After that I follow the process that you described:
- sbt eclipse
- And import the existing project into Eclipse

Here are the Giter8 templates:

https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/wiki/giter8-templates